Influence of covariance on the LDA functions
I'm trying to understand the behavior of Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) in a dataset where a certain variable(s) is highly correlated with many others, yet - let's say for the sake of simplicity this specific variable, variable 1- exhibits tiny class variance (e.g., pooled variance is 0.01 and group's mean distance vector is 0.09). Despite its surprisingly high weighting in the LDA loading, this variable(s) does not effectively discriminate between classes, at all.
In contrast, I have identified another variable, variable 2, that serves as a near-perfect discriminator (it has a pooled variance of 0.1 so one order magnitude larger than variable 1 and a distance vector of 0.77 between class means, but is uncorrelated with the other variables.
I’ve noticed that the highly correlated, less discriminative variable receives more weight in the LDA loadings than the strong discriminator variable 2. This has led me to question how LDA handles correlation and covariance when determining the importance of variables. Specifically, I'm struggling to find the math behind how covariance influences the LDA model and the potential "breaking point" at which correlated variables might obscure the identification of truly significant discriminators. What are the boundary conditions that determine how correlation/covariance affects the effectiveness of LDA as a tool for identifying the best discriminators?
How I see it is that variances simply just scale the resulting LDA vector while when covariances are not 0 they rotate the resulting vector and I suspect that is where variable 1 gets more weight than variable 2 cuz kinda variable 1 explains or resolves more of the noise coming from other variables due to their correlatedness. in any case, these are my thoughts but I am at a point where I need a piece of information to make this whole story make sense to gain better understanding of how actually lda work and when should one be careful of interpreting its results. Thank you!
P.S. Naturally I assume equal covariance matrices of the two classes. My question is about the influence of strong relationships between variables with redundant information.

Can you give us a link to this data, or some manufactured data showing the same problem? Then it can be investigated!
